# How to change the output folder for migrations with asp.net Core?

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework, asp.net-core, command-line-interface

Does anyone know how to change the output directory of the following command?

```
dotnet ef  migrations add Initial --context EsportshubApi.Models.ApplicationDbContext
```

I tried to add the option:

```
--content-root-path 'Migrations/Identity'
```

But that doesn't do anything. There is a `--data-dir` option as well and something else with directory. But none of them is the output for migrations.

My problem is that I have 2 DbContexts so I want their migrations to be separated.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

```cs
dotnet ef migrations add Initial --context EsportshubApi.Models.ApplicationDbContext -o YourFolderPath
```

## `dotnet ef migrations add`

Adds a new migration.

Arguments:

| Argument | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `<NAME>` | The name of the migration. |

Options:

| Option | Short | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `--output-dir <PATH>` | `-o` | The directory used to output the files. Paths are relative to the target project directory. Defaults to "Migrations". |
| `--namespace <NAMESPACE>` | `-n` | The namespace to use for the generated classes. Defaults to generated from the output directory. Added in EF Core 5.0. |

Also here are the [common options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#common-options) you can use with this command.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-migrations-add)

Comment: Do you know how to set the folder in C#? I'd prefer not to use an extra argument each time.

Comment: In the previous EntityFramework version, you were able to set the migrations folder in the `Configuration()` method and the `dotnet ef` commands compile the application so it's entirely possible you would be able to set the migration folder using C#.

Comment: Sorry I forgot about that. It's been a while I didn't touch this

Comment: Also fun fact, after you set the `--output` directory once e.g. `./Config/Migrations`, future migrations are automatically created in the folder even without the argument.

Comment: @LeviFuller interesting

Comment: @LeviFuller nice but it would be nice if we could define that somewhere like dotnet-tools.json or even in csproj

Answer (score 87):

For `Package Manager Console` run this command:

```
PM> Add-Migration 001 -OutputDir "Data/Migrations"
```

My structure is:

```
.AspCoreProject
  -Data
    -Migrations
       20190721162938_001.cs
       MainDbContextModelSnapshot.cs
```

**Update:**

For removing last migration use:

```
PM> Remove-Migration
```

Note: If the migration is already applied to the database, then you will get this error:

> The migration '20190721162938_001' has already been applied to the database. Revert it and try again. If the migration has been applied to other databases, consider reverting its changes using a new migration.

Then run:

```
PM> Remove-Migration -Force
```

If your migration is not the last migration. first, rollback to the migration you need by `Update-Database` then delete all migration classes after that migration.

```
PM> Update-Database -Migration 001
```

This will revert all migrations after `001`

Comment: could you add the remove command as well `Remove-Migration 001 -OutputDir "Data/Migrations"` not working neither does `Remove-Migration 001"`

Answer (score 15):

In EF Core 5.0, you are free to move Migration files and changes their namespace manually. New migrations are created as siblings of the last migration. Alternatively, you can specify the directory at generation time as follows:

> .Net core CLI

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --output-dir Your/Directory
```

> Package Manager Console

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate -OutputDir Your\Directory
```

[EF Core 5.0 documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/managing?tabs=vs)

Answer (score 4):

You just need to use -o Or --output option with your command,

To do so, you need to explore to your root project folder, eg: C:\project\SampleAPi\
and use this command

```
dotnet ef  migrations add DbInitial --context SampleAPi.Infrastructure.DbContext -o Infrastructure/Migrations
```

and then

```
dotnet ef database update
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I was able to solve by replacing relative path character '\' with '/'.

Worked syntax:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --project Infrastructure --startup-project MyProject.API --output-dir Persistence/Migrations
```

Please notice - I changed 'Persistence\Migrations' to 'Persistence/Migrations' by replacing '\' with '/'

This is what I initially tried (in mac os):

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --project Infrastructure --startup-project MyProject.API --output-dir Persistence\Migrations
```

The above command created 'PersistenceMigrations' folder under the Infrastructure project. But the expected folder structure was Persistence\Migrations.

Note: 'InitialCreate' is the migration name.